# Kotlin multiple suspend cancellable coroutine

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I have a problem with coroutines. I use one coroutine and I want to do second in the first one. I have a bug when I try to run second coroutine : "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body". I have everywhere coroutines so where is problem? Here is code:

```
 suspend fun firstCoroutine(): List<Decks> {

    val activeLanguage = userService.getActiveLanguage() ?: return emptyList()

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->

        db.collection("Decks")
            .whereArrayContains("languages", activeLanguage)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->

                val items = ArrayList<Decks>()

                if (documents != null) {
                    for (document in documents) {
                        val id: String = document.id

                        var knowCountForDeck: Int = secondCoroutine(id). <-- here is problem
                        
                        val name: String = document.data["name"] as String
                        val languages: List<String> =
                            document.data["languages"] as List<String>
                        items.add(Decks(id, name, languages))
                    }

                }
                continuation.resume(items)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { err ->
                continuation.resumeWithException(err)
            }
    }
}

suspend fun secondCoroutine(collectionId: String): Int {

    val userId = userService.getCurrentUserId() ?: return 0

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->

        db.collection("Users").document(userId).collection(collectionId).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { cards ->

                var knowCountForDeck = 0

                if (!cards.isEmpty) {
                    for (card in cards) {
                        if (card.data["status"] == "know") {
                            knowCountForDeck += 1
                        }
                    }
                }
                continuation.resume(knowCountForDeck)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { err ->
                continuation.resumeWithException(err)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: addOnSuccessListener is not on a coroutine body/scope.

Comment: so what should I do now? When I do only one coroutine like this everything works.

Comment: In my experience it is best if you instead call secondCoroutine outside the suspendCancellableCoroutine on firstCoroutine, that is, return documents from this suspendCancellableCoroutine and continue the processing on firstCoroutine, which will allow you to call the secondCoroutine with no problem since it is a suspend scope. An even better architecture is to separate these 2 functions and call them from a third function, which reduces coupling between firstCoroutine and secondCoroutine.

Comment: you are not using `knowCountForDeck` anywhere in first suspend function, then why are you calling `secondCoroutine` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call a coroutine from a callback, which is not part of your coroutine so it can't call suspend functions.

One of the main advantages of coroutines is that you can avoid using callbacks and write your code sequentially.

Many APIs already include suspend function alternatives to using callbacks. If I'm correct in guessing you're using Firebase, you can use the suspend function `await()` instead of using listeners. Then you don't need to use `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to convert your callbacks into a suspend function:

```
suspend fun firstCoroutine(): List<Decks> {

    val activeLanguage = userService.getActiveLanguage() ?: return emptyList()

    val documents = db.collection("Decks")
        .whereArrayContains("languages", activeLanguage)
        .get()
        .await()
    val items = documents.map { document ->
        val id: String = document.id

        var knowCountForDeck: Int = someSuspendFunction(id)

        val name: String = document.data["name"] as String
        val languages: List<String> =
            document.data["languages"] as List<String>
        Decks(id, name, languages)
    }
    return items
}
```

If you were working with an API that doesn't have a suspend function available, then to write your own with `suspendCoroutine`, I suggest writing a bare bones version that can work with any Task, and then use that within your specific application code. It would looks something like this:

```
suspend fun <T> Task<T>.await() = suspendCoroutine<T> { continuation ->
    addOnSuccessListener {
        continuation.resume(it)
    }
    addOnFailureListener {
        continuation.resumeWithException(it)
    }
}
```

Or to follow Kotlin conventions better, you can return null instead of throwing an exception on recoverable failures:

```
suspend fun <T: Any> Task<T>.awaitResultOrNull(): T? = suspendCoroutine<T> { continuation ->
    addOnSuccessListener {
        continuation.resume(it)
    }
    addOnFailureListener {
        continuation.resume(null)
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that `await()` throws an Exception on failure, so you may want to wrap it in try/catch. But I was duplicating the functionality you seemed to be trying in your code, where it also throws an exception on failure.

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be solved by moving the call to `secondCoroutine` function inside the calling coroutine

```
yourScope.launch{
   val decks = firstCoroutine()  
   decks.forEach{
       val countForDeck = secondCoroutine(it.id)
       // Do something with countForDeck
   }
}
```